# Why do we say that accidents/housefires "take place" ?

Tags: phrases, collocation, mass-media

> Accident Took Place At Ukraine Nuclear Power Plant.

Take place : You say that **an event takes place**.

- The wedding took place on the stage of the Sydney Opera House.
- Elections will take place in November.

> Is this sentence " [accident took place at a nuclear power plant](http://www.zerohedge.com/news/2014-12-03/accident-took-place-ukraine-nuclear-power-plant-prime-minister-reveals)",
> a good example to quote because accidents, housefires etc. are accidental.

Some clarification please.

Comment: What does the concept of accidental vs deliberate/intentional have to do with the phrasal verb *take place*? If something occurred, i.e. was an event in time and space, it *took place*. Doesn't matter if someone planned it or not. Where did you get the idea that that mattered?

Comment: Are accidents and fires not events? They happen, they occur. The ODO definition of _event_ is indeed “a thing that happens _or takes place_”. And why the asterisks in _Ukraine_? As far as I am aware, _Ukraine_ is not an expletive and need not be bowdlerised in titles.

Comment: @DanBron, Thanks. A Journalist friend's comment that  accidents and housefires happen, they don't take place, got me thinking.

Comment: Voting to close because the question is based on a false premise (that things which *take place* must have been planned), which I think has been elucidated to the OP's satisfaction.

Comment: 'Manifest' and 'take place' have an obvious connection.

Comment: @Manish . Your friend got a supporter. This post (http://news.nationalpost.com/full-comment/bill-boyd-on-journalistic-cliches-basically-the-fact-is-in-terms-of-thinking-outside-the-box) probably got you and your friend thinking.

Comment: Voting to close, I am enlightened. Thank You All Nice People.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggest [this](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/take+place) page to Journalist your friend.

> [You can use take place to talk about either planned or unplanned
>   events.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/take+place)
>
> - The talks will take place in Vienna
> - The **accident took place** on Saturday morning.

Comment: You can use **happen and occur** to talk about planned events, as well. None of the usage restrictions implicit in the original question or explicit in your answer are real.

Comment: @webbcode, I concur, I use happen and occur to talk about planned events. Reference removed.

Comment: downvote removed.

Comment: @MystiSinha, MORE THAN THE ANSWER, thanks for the link to the post.